# How to merge multi array of object in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have two list of array, I don't know How I can merge multi array of object in python?

```
[{'name': 'James'}, {'name': 'Abhinay'}, {'name': 'Peter'}]

[{'age': 1}, {'age': 2}, {'age': 3}]
```

what I want

```
[{'name': 'James','age':1}, {'name': 'Abhinay','age':2}, {'name': 'Peter','age':3}]
```

Comment: You've tagged this as Python 2.7 and 3.X, which version(s) is this required for?

Comment: The possible solutions differ quite a bit depending on if you want python2.7 or 3.x. What are you tageting?

Comment: @BTables I fixed it

Comment: @IainShelvington I fixed it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one approach that can work:

```py
L1 = [{'name': 'James'}, {'name': 'Abhinay'}, {'name': 'Peter'}]
L2 = [{'age': 1}, {'age': 2}, {'age': 3}]

result = [dict(**x, **y) for x, y in zip(L1, L2)]

print(result)
# [{'name': 'James', 'age': 1}, {'name': 'Abhinay', 'age': 2}, {'name': 'Peter', 'age': 3}]
```

Using the dict union `|` operator in Python 3.9 or higher:

```py
result = [x | y for x, y in zip(L1, L2)]
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if I have more than two arrays?

Comment: I got this error: "TypeError: attribute of type 'NoneType' is not callable"

Comment: @user12217822 the pattern is extendable, for 3 list you would use `[x | y | z for x, y, z in zip(L1, L2, L3)]`

Comment: @user12217822 Given code works perfectly and produces desired output.

Comment: @user12217822 You've probably overwritten the `dict` or `zip` built-in names

Comment: yes, that's what I would think would be the issue there